# why my simple application doesn't run?

Tags: android

Here is the codes.

```
package com.example.appfit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

class Main extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.select);

    }

}
```

I can't get, when I try to run this I'm getting unfortunately stopped, problem. Also here is the select.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSelect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/select"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

What may problem be?

Also Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.appfit"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.appfit.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I don't know how to get errors? I'm really newbie.

Comment: Try connecting to the device log via: 'adb -e logcat' for the emulator or 'adb -d logcat' for the device - It will give you full stack dump.

Comment: Use Logcat. Maybe post your android manifest

Comment: Go to Window -> show view -> logcat

Comment: @Manishika there is already logcat but how to post it here?

Comment: Run your application and logcat will show the errors.Copy your error from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
class Main extends Activity{
```

to

```
public class Main extends Activity{
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have declared your activity in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

The possible problems may be that you have not mentioned the Main Launcher in manifest. Check that what path have you given in manifest. And also ensure that you have mentioned the string select in Strings.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the Android Manifest file. Your activity needs to be properly registered as the "Launch Activity". It should look something like this in the Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.appfit.Main"
    android:label="@string/your_app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```